# Оценочное существительное: дефис или раздельно?

Tags: приложение, раздельно-дефис

Какую **форму написания** нужно выбрать и почему:

(1) ***Бездельник (?) кот** опять сломал цветок.  Заняться ему больше нечем.*

(2) *Этот кот опять спит. Вот это жизнь! **Бездельник (?) кот!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ***Бездельник-кот** опять сломал цветок. Заняться ему больше нечем*.

Сейчас, видимо, следует писать через дефис, по [справочнику Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp120.php):

> **§ 120.** Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных пишутся через **дефис**.
> **1.** Сочетания двух существительных, в которых первая часть обладает самостоятельным склонением:
> <...>
> **в)** сочетания с однословными приложениями, предшествующими определяемому слову, напр.: *старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, трудяга-следователь, профан-редактор, пройдоха-управляющий*. **Такие приложения носят оценочный характер**.

По [Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) (Обособленные приложения, пункт 4-1) писали бы раздельно: *красавец мужчина* (ср.: *красивый мужчина*), *старик отец, гигант завод* (но: *завод-гигант*), *бедняк сапожник, богатырь всадник, крошка сиротка, хищник волк, искусник повар.*

В этих случаях приложение может быть по значению приравнено к определению-прилагательному.
***Бездельный кот*** – сомнительное сочетание. Но ведь необязательно подбирать однокоренное прилагательное. *Праздный, ленивый?*.. Главное – значение слова.
А почему, собственно, он бездельник? Ведь нашёл же себе дело – сломал цветок.
Ещё у Розенталя также написано (это так, к размышлению):

> Следует, однако, заметить, что приложение-существительное может по смыслу отличаться от определения-прилагательного; так, в предложении *Татьяна по воле барыни была выдана замуж за пьяницу башмачника* (Т.) сочетание *пьяница башмачник* (постоянный признак) не то же, что *пьяный башмачник* (временный признак).

Так что, думаю, раздельное написание тоже можно оправдать. А если ***кот*** превратится в имя собственное, то тем более.

2. *Этот кот опять спит. Вот это жизнь! **Бездельник кот!***

Здесь оценочное существительное выступает в роли сказуемого. Пишем раздельно.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне понравилось! И знаете, дефисное написание по Лопатину здесь даже лучше подходит; эти существительные создают единый образ, поэтому произношение слитное, с равноправными ударениями. А в именном сказуемом, ударение, как я думаю, уходит на первое слово.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо и вам! Ну да, во втором примере по-другому и не произнесёшь, и не напишешь.